# Am I using appropriate methods in this login system?

Tags: java, authentication, jdbc, servlets, jsp

I have had to do a crash course in JSP, Servlets, and JDBC. I decided to attempt a Login System. I'm unsure if my use of try/catch is appropriate and if I am closing database connections correctly. There is one major flaw in the program which is if a user registering enters an ID that is not unique, then it causes an exception. I'm unsure how to solve this. I realize this is a lot of code to pore through, but any suggestions would be much appreciated.

**Index.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3> Welcome to the Login Screen</h3>
<br>
<form action = 'login' method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "userId"/>
<br>
<input type = "password" name = "password"/>
<br>
<input type = "submit"/>
</form>
<br>
<a href="registration.jsp">I dont have an account</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Profile.jsp**

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Welcome to the profile page</h3>
<br>
<jsp:useBean id="user" class = "com.calgar.service.User" scope = "session"></jsp:useBean>
Welcome <jsp:getProperty property="firstName" name="user"/> <jsp:getProperty property="lastName" name="user"/> 
<br>Your User ID : <jsp:getProperty property="userId" name="user"/>
<br>Your Password is :<jsp:getProperty property="password" name="user"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Registration.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Enter Your details here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Enter User ID</h3>
<br>
<form action = "RegistrationServlet" method = "post">
Enter User ID : <input type = "text"  name ="newUserId"/>
<br>Enter your Password : <input type = "password" name ="newUserPassword"/>
<br>Enter your First Name :<input type = "text" name = "newUserFirstName"/>
<br>Enter your Last Name : <input type = "text" name ="newUserLastName"/>
<br><input type = "submit"/>
<br>
<%String name =(String)request.getAttribute("GenericSQLError"); %>
<%=name %>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login Servlet**

```java
package com.calgar.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.calgar.service.LoginService;
import com.calgar.service.User;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userId,password;
        userId = request.getParameter("userId");
        password = request.getParameter("password");

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        boolean authenticated = false;

        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();

        try {
            connection=loginService.getConnection(connection);
            resultSet = loginService.getUserLoginCredentials(preparedStatement, connection, resultSet);
            authenticated = loginService.authenticate(userId,password,resultSet);

            if(authenticated)
            {
                User user = new User();
                user = loginService.getUserDetails(userId, preparedStatement, connection, resultSet);
                request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
                response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");
            }
            else
            {   
                loginService.closeDatabaseConnections(preparedStatement, connection, resultSet);
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

**Registration Servlet**

```java
package com.calgar.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.calgar.service.LoginService;
import com.calgar.service.User;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegistrationServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/RegistrationServlet")
public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public RegistrationServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement  preparedStatement = null;
        String newUserId, newUserPassword, newUserFirstName, newUserLastName;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        newUserId = request.getParameter("newUserId");
        newUserPassword = request.getParameter("newUserPassword");
        newUserFirstName= request.getParameter("newUserFirstName");
        newUserLastName = request.getParameter("newUserLastName");
        System.out.println(newUserId);


        try {

            LoginService loginService = new LoginService();
            connection = loginService.getConnection(connection);
            loginService.addNewUser(preparedStatement, connection, newUserId, newUserPassword, newUserFirstName, newUserLastName);
            loginService.closeDatabaseConnections(preparedStatement, connection, resultSet);

            User user = new User();
            user.setUserId(newUserId);
            user.setPassword(newUserPassword);
            user.setFirstName(newUserFirstName);
            user.setLastName(newUserLastName);

            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(connection != null)
                try{connection.close();}
                catch(SQLException ignore){}

            if(preparedStatement != null)
                try{preparedStatement.close();}
                catch(SQLException ignore){}

            if(resultSet != null)
                try{resultSet.close();}
                catch(SQLException ignore){}

        }

    }



}
```

**LoginService**

```java
package com.calgar.service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginService {

    public Connection getConnection(Connection connection) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        System.out.println("Connecting to database USERS");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","calgar","password");
        System.out.println("Connection successful");
        return connection;
    }

    public ResultSet getUserLoginCredentials(PreparedStatement ps,Connection connection, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        ps =connection.prepareStatement("SELECT userId, password FROM users");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    }

    public boolean authenticate(String UserId, String password, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        String userIdResultSet,passwordResultSet;
        //Boolean authenticated = false;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            userIdResultSet = rs.getString(1);
            passwordResultSet = rs.getString(2);
             if(userIdResultSet.equals(UserId))
             {
                if(passwordResultSet.equals(password))
                        {
                         return true;
                        }
             }
        }
        return false;

    }

    public User getUserDetails(String userId, PreparedStatement ps,Connection connection, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        User user = new User();

        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT userId, password, userFirstName, userLastName FROM users WHERE  userId = ?" );
        ps.setString(1, userId);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next())
        {

            user.setUserId(rs.getString(1));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString(2));
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString(3));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString(4));
        }

        return user;
    }

    public void addNewUser(PreparedStatement ps, Connection connection, String newUserId, String newUserPassword,String newUserFirstName,String newUserLastname) throws SQLException
    {
        if (newUserId != null && "".equals(newUserId.trim())){
                newUserId = null;
        }
            if ((newUserPassword != null) && (newUserPassword.trim().equals(""))){
                newUserPassword = null;
            }
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO users (userId ,password , userFirstName, userLastName)VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, newUserId);
        ps.setString(2, newUserPassword);
        ps.setString(3, newUserFirstName);
        ps.setString(4, newUserLastname);

        ps.executeUpdate();

    }

    public void closeDatabaseConnections(PreparedStatement ps,Connection connection, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
    {
        if(ps != null)
        {
        ps.close();
        }
        if(connection!=null)
        {
        connection.close();
        }
        if(rs != null)
        {
        rs.close();
        }

    }

}
```

**User**

```java
package com.calgar.service;

public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the functions in `LoginService` take unnecessary parameters. For example, `getConnection()` takes a `connection` parameter, but never uses it. It just reassigns and returns it. It could be written like this instead:

```
public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    System.out.println("Connecting to database USERS");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login","calgar","password");
    System.out.println("Connection successful");
    return connection;
}
```

Same thing with `ps` and `rs` in `getUserLoginCredentials()`, etc.

---

The database resources are not being closed properly. Make sure you wrap the use of each resource in a `try` and close it in the `finally`. This goes for all database resources, including `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet`.

```
Connection connection = getConnection();
try {
    // use connection
}
finally {
    connection.close()
}
```

If you are using Java 7, you should check out the new [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. The above could be written like this:

```
try (Connection connection = getConnection()) {
    // use connection
} // connection will automatically be closed here
```

---

Rather than declaring all variables at the top of a function, consider moving the variable declarations closer to where they are used. For example, rather than this:

```
String newUserId, newUserPassword, newUserFirstName, newUserLastName;
...

newUserId = request.getParameter("newUserId");
newUserPassword = request.getParameter("newUserPassword");
newUserFirstName= request.getParameter("newUserFirstName");
newUserLastName = request.getParameter("newUserLastName");
```

Do this:

```
String newUserId = request.getParameter("newUserId");
String newUserPassword = request.getParameter("newUserPassword");
String newUserFirstName= request.getParameter("newUserFirstName");
String newUserLastName = request.getParameter("newUserLastName");
```

This will eliminate several lines of code and make it a little easier to read.

---

You could also get rid of the constructors in the servlet classes. They will be generated by the compiler automatically.